# CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, opencv

So I use OpenCV 3.0 compiled by myself with the help of MinGW. I write and build in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows. And `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL| CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` as the arugment of `namedWindow()` doesn't seem to restrict resizin of my window and what I've noticed is that `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL=0`, `CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO=0`. Any explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember the parameter does not apply to the window itself but to the content image of the window.

That means that you still can freely resize your window but the displayed image keeps its ratio and is surrounded by black (or what ever colored) bars instead being stretched ill-proportionally.

edit:
Excerpt from the [namedWindow-Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow)

> Note
>
> Qt backend supports additional flags:
>
> CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO or CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO: CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO
>   adjusts the image with no respect to its ratio, whereas
>   CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO keeps the image ratio.
>   [...]

please note the QT-constraint.

Your second question about the definition of the flags:
I think the reason that both are zero is, because there multiple groups of exlusive options. (Normal window <-> fixed size window; free scalability <-> ratio keeping scalability). You do not a own bit for each of this options because. So the default is simply an anuset bit. The reason for making a define for it is simply better readability and code understanding.

Comment: @Ilia it is - please see the link and note the difference in the wording. Some flags are related to 'window' and some flags are related to 'image'

Comment: I see you didnt get what I was talking about so heres the gif for you http://vk.com/doc13632015_437004532

Comment: @Ilia ok now i could view your animation. it looks wrong ;) but your question is misleading in my opinion. `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL` explicitly allows resizingof the window. however please note that the Documentation states that the `CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` flag may be only available if you are using a QT-Backend